# My Safari download button has disappeared

Tags: macos, safari

For some odd reason, I am unable to witness my download button, even when i am downloading something. I am able to access the downloaded file(s) in Finder just fine, but theres no download button for me to access it, open, and/or drag and drop the file in Safari itself. Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you accidentally removed the download button from the Toolbar.

1. Safari menu: View > Customise Toolbar
2. Add download button by dragging it to the Toolbar

[image: Screenshot Safari Toolbar Customiser]

Comment: For some reason though, the downloads button isn't appearing among the "items" to drag into the toolbar.

Comment: What if you drag the default set of icons in?

Comment: That hasn't worked either

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue on my own Mac. What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: The issue is gone now, I think it is because i changed the "clear downloads queue" to after safari quits

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and, even after following some tips, the problem persisted.

In my case, **fixing** this bug required 4 basic steps.

I hope the tips below can help you:

1. If it is an option in your View->"Customize Toolbar" buttons,
   drag it to your toolbar (otherwise it is kept there, in toolbar, by
   default - since item 2 is okay)
2. Make sure Safari->Preferences->General->"Remove download list items" is set as "Manually"
3. Downloading **anything** to keep something in 'download list'.
4. Make sure (at least in the 'very first time') you are NOT in "private window".

Even though I followed steps 1 through 3, my solution came after downloading a file in public window.

Afterwards, download button was visible again even to my private windows.

Answer (score 0):

The downloads button will re-appear after your next download

Answer (score 0):

The download button will not only reappear after your next download, but will again disappear if you clear your downloads.

It's not a bug, it's a "feature".